# Registering a MediatR pipeline constrained PostProcessor using ASP.NET Core DI

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, mediatr

Previously, we had the following pipeline setup working for auditlogging purposes

```
    public class AuditLogPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> : 
           IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> 
              where TRequest : IAuditLogRequest<TResponse>
```

Where IAuditLogRequest implements IRequest

```
public interface IAuditLogRequest<TResponse> : IRequest<TResponse>
```

All and only the Commands that implement the IAuditLogRequest reached the AuditLogPostProcessor.

Registration using SimpleInjector was as follows

```
_container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IRequestPostProcessor<,>), 
    new[] { typeof(GenericRequestPostProcessor<,>),typeof(AuditLogPostProcessor<,>) });
```

Currently, we use the ASP.NET Core DI for our Dependence Injection with the following registration.

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRequestPostProcessor<,>), typeof(GenericRequestPostProcessor<,>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRequestPostProcessor<,>), typeof(AuditLogPostProcessor<,>));
```

When a Command implements the IRequest, we get the error

```
TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'Command', 
on 'AuditLogPostProcessor`2[TRequest,TResponse]' violates 
the constraint of type parameter 'TRequest'.
```

So it seems the DI is not honoring the constraint. Can I get the desired behavior with the ASP.NET Core DI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking to do exactly the same thing. Apparently ASP.net core DI does not support this feature.

SRC: [Support constrained open generic types](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/471)

You need to use another container such as Autofac or StructureMap.
Example: [Autofac for ASP.NET core](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html)

It's very simple and it does not require much changes

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar setup.

If your handler implements IRequestPostProcessor, all you need to do is add this to your DI :

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPostProcessorBehavior<,>));
```